# In XNA, how do I modify something in the main game class from another class?

Tags: c#, xna

Okay, by default, the `Game` class for an XNA PC game has a public bool attribute called `IsMouseVisible`, which when set enables/disables the mouse being visible. I have another class called `Configs` which monitors specific keys being pressed. Now what I want to do is set it so that when I press a specific key, it will change the value of `IsMouseVisible`. This is where I get stuck because I don't know how to change the value from another class.

I know that I could just create a bool value in the `Configs` class and make it so that when the key is pressed, the value will change, then make it so that when the main `Game` class updates, it sets the value for `IsMouseVisible` to the Configs class' value, but the thing is, I might want to create multiple different values (not just `IsMouseVisible`) that can be set in the main `Game` class from another class.

And there's my question, how could I set something in the main `Game` class from another class?
(Without having to create multiple updates for each and every value I want to be accessible.)

Comment: without codes, hard to tell

Answer (score 3):

Create the object 'Configs' in the main class's constructor. While doing this, give the Config objects a reference to the main class. Now Configs can access the main class's value.

Comment: Does this mean that I would have to create a local game class in the Configs class to get/set the value of something in the main game?

Comment: Okay so in my main game class I created the class Configs and named it configs. Then in the constructor set the class configs like this:    configs = new Config(this,this). (The class is a game component so the first parameter is the game and the second parameter is my ref for the game) The only problem is that I am getting an error telling me that "this" (the game) can't be used as a ref or and out because "this" is read only. How do I fix that problem?

Comment: This is correct, but in the specific context of an XNA `GameComponent` object, it is redundant.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass a reference of the game class to the Configs class. In the Configs' class constructor, set a private member variable to the instance of the game class. From there you can manipulate the game. See below:

Game Class

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    Configs configs; 

    GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
    SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;

    public Game1()
    {
        _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // Pass THIS game instance to the Configs class constructor.
        configs = new Configs(this);
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Configs Class

```
public class Configs
{
    // Reference to the main game class.
    private Game _game;

    public Configs(Game game)
    {
       // Store the game reference to a local variable.
        _game = game;
    }

    public void SetMouseVisible()
    {
        // This is a reference to you main game class that was 
        // passed to the Configs class constructor.
        _game.IsMouseVisible = true;
    }
}
```

This is basically what others have been stating. However, it seems you are having a rough time understanding the concepts without seeing some code. Therefore, I provided it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to do it without creating a new reference of the game in the class. But say I had an object in my game class and the game class switches the value of the object, how could I get/set that specific object's value?

Answer (score 0):

Three things, and they all relate to your comments on the answer from @Patashu:

First, if you are passing a `Game` object into your constructor, you don't need to set it as a ref type argument, because it is automatically passed by reference (by virtue of being an object).

Second, the reason your `GameComponent` subclass needs a reference to the `Game` object in its default constructor...is that it already has a reference to `Game` built into it.  In your `Configs` class, call `this.Game`  That is the main `Game` instance.

Third, If your constructor already recieves one argument of an object, it does not need another argument of the same instance of the same object.

[Read the documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent.game.aspx)  It's useful.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I got am able to get the IsMouseVisible value and set it now, I never noticed that you could get/set the game's implemented object values from "this" or just "Game". But I am now having a problem, what if I had an object in my game class and the game class switches the value of the object, how could I get/set that specific object's value from the other class?

Comment: Other objects implemented by you can be accessed in the same way.  But if you have something specific in mind, you should post another question and include your code.